# Things to consider before using message broker

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, messagebroker

I am newbee in message broker area . Currently there are quiet a good no. of message broker are there(Rabbit-mq ,zeromq ,kafka and many more).

Want to know which thing to consider while opting for any message broker for backend architecture .

Answer (score 1):

Route messages to one or more of many destinations

Transform messages to an alternative representation

Perform message aggregation, decomposing messages into multiple messages and sending them to their destination, then recomposing the responses into one message to return to the user

Interact with an external repository to augment a message or store it

Invoke Web services to retrieve data

Respond to events or errors

Provide content and topic-based message routing using the publish–subscribe pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker

Try to use **RabbitMq**, simple and fast.